# C++ memory management clarification

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm new to c++.

I've got a `Rectangle` class. When I create a `Rectangle` object like this:

```
Rectangle R1(10,10,90,20);
```

- Does R1 sit on the heap or stack?
- If I were to create it using the `new` operator, would only then it be on the heap?

(In general what would be the correct way to create an object in c++?)

To my understanding, if I create it without `new` the object sits on the stack and does not need to be deleted at the end of its life time. And if do create it with new

```
Rectangle* R = new Rectangle(1,1,1,1);
```

it will be placed on the heap and would need to be de-allocated using `delete`.

Comment: There must be a duplicate of this.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy i came across this while doing my home work 
it wasn't part of it , it was more of a general wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Rectangle R1(10,10,90,20);
```

This creates a variable with "automatic" duration.  It is automatically destroyed when the code flow exits the scope.  If it's not in a function, that means when the execution of your code completes.  Usually (but not always) it sits on some sort of stack.

```
Rectangle* R = new Rectangle(1,1,1,1);
Rectangle* P(new Rectangle(1,1,1,1)); //rarely used
```

This part is confusing: The variable `R` is a pointer with automatic duration (like above).  It points at an `Rectangle` with "dynamic" duration.  Usually (but not always) the dynamic object sits on some sort of heap.  The rectangle is destroyed only when you explicitly destroy it with `delete R;`.  This means if the function ends and there is no other copy of `R`, it becomes impossible to delete, and will remain in memory until your program ends.  This is called a memory leak.

In C++, dynamic memory is best handled with a smart pointer, such as `std::unique_ptr`, so that you can't accidentally forget to delete it, even if the code is crashing.

```
std::unique_ptr<Rectangle> R(new Rectangle(1,1,1,1));
```

Comment: Note that if the `Rectangle *` goes out of scope (e.g. function call returns) without `delete R` being called, you will create a memory leak.

Comment: thanks, i wasn't sure if i needed to delete R1
you've made it very clear that i don't 
thanks for the insight :)

Comment: I clarified the difference between the pointer and the Rectangle on the heap.  I hope.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of the things you say are either implementation details or dependent on the context. Consider this:

```
// file.cpp

Rectangle r1(1,2,3,4);

int main()
{
  Rectangle r2 = r1;
  Rectangle * r3 = new Rectangle(r1);
}
```

Here `r1` has *static storage* and *static (= permanent) lifetime*, while `r2` has *automatic storage* and *automatic (= scoped) lifetime*. That is, `r1` constructed at program start and destroyed at the end (after `main` returns), while `r2` is constructed at declaration and destroyed at the end of its scope (i.e. the function body scope in this case).

The pointer `r3` points to a `Rectangle` object of *dynamic storage* and *dynamic (= manual) lifetime*. The object `*r3` comes to life at the `new` expression, and it will only be destroyed at the user's request via a matching `delete` expression (or perhaps a manual destructor call). Since we don't destroy it, this is in fact a *leak*.

Nothing is known about the *memory* used by `*r3`, other than that this memory is allocated by the static member function `Rectangle::operator new()` if it exists, or otherwise by the global allocation function `::operator new`. The global version's memory is typically referred to as the "free store".

(All three objects `r1`, `r2` and `*r3` are supposedly equal, since `r2` and `*r3` are constructed as copies of `r1`.)

The situation gets even more interesting when you consider member variables: `struct Foo { Rectangle r; };`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `R1` is created with automatic storage duration.  This means that, in practice, it will be allocated on a stack-like structure.  It doesn't have to be mind you, a 'stack' is just convenient and common.  You have to call `new` (or `malloc` if you really want to for some silly reason... don't) to allocate memory dynamically.
2. See above.
3. Yes, anything you `new` you must `delete`.  Typically a class will manage this for you.  Take for example an `std::vector<T>`.  You allocate the `vector` on the stack, but the internal data (i.e., an array of T) is allocated dynamically.  When the `vector` goes out of scope it `delete []`s the dynamically allocated array for you in it's destructor, allowing you to remain pleasantly ignorant of the underlying memory management details.